# What's the best method to iterate through CSV file, make an API call, and append results in new column in CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV extract from a SQL table with the following records:

```
Brand name1, Product name1, 
Brand name2, Product name2,
Brand name3, Product name3, 
. 
.
.
```

What's the best method to loop through each record, make an API call, and take a component of the response and append it to a new column in the data structure?

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, show us your code. As is, it seems like you didn't try and want someone to write code for you. Ruby's [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) documentation nicely explains how to read a file, and the examples would be great starting points for what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry this was such an open-ended question.  These CSV docs are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, open a "newdata.csv", for append, then, use IO.readlines for read by lines the SQL based CSV. Cast you spell and append the new line

```
# open a file for append
fichero=File.open('newdata.csv','a')

# read the sql based .csv file, by lines
for linea in IO.readlines('sqlbased.csv')

  # make your api call here
  @data=api.call(:spell=>:cast)

  # write a new line with your data
  fichero.puts linea+', '+@data

end
```

Comment: Don't try to manually create or modify a CSV file by naively inserting commas between columns. CSV isn't that simple, especially if the data being inserted contains commas.

Answer (score -1):

The first example in the CSV documentation for [reading from a CSV file line-by-line](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-A+Line+at+a+Time) is:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

The first example for [writing to a CSV file](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-To+a+File) is:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

Those are the basis for what you want to do:

```
require 'csv'

def some_method(ary)
  brand, product = *ary
  [brand, product].map{ |s| s.split.last }.join(':')
end

CSV.open('test2.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
    new_data = some_method(row)
    csv << [*row, new_data]  
  end
end
```

Looking at "test2.csv" shows it's had the new column added:

```
Brand name1, Product name1,name1:name1
Brand name2, Product name2,name2:name2
Brand name3, Product name3,name3:name3
```